Filter getByRole locator by attribute of same element
Given the following html:
...
<div class="table">
  <div role="row" row-id="1">...</div>
  <div role="row" row-id="2">...</div>
<div>
...

How can I use the getByRole('row') locator to get the div with row-id="1"?
Using getByRole('row').filter('[row-id="1"]') doesn't work as filter seems to be applied on the child elements only.
However according to the documentation, the filter locator "is queried starting with the outer locator match", so the filter should actually work? Am I missing something?
Using the argument options.name of getByRole() is not an option.

It's always good to share a more complete HTML tree, as per these guidelines for web automation questions on meta. The reason is, sometimes the best way to select an element has to do with context not provided here. Are you using Playwright-test or just plain Playwright? Web scraping or testing? And if you can share the actual site, your main goal, and a [mcve], that's ideal. Thanks.

If you're trying to assert on the text content, the cleanest approach is to use getByRole's name: key:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<div class="table">
  <div role="row" row-id="1">A</div>
  <div role="row" row-id="2">B</div>
<div>
</body></html>`;

test("Row 1 has text 'A'", async ({page}) => {
  await page.setContent(html);
  await expect(page.getByRole("row", {name: "A", exact: true})).toBeVisible();
});

If you don't want to assert on the text, :scope is also possible, allowing you to include the current node in the query context:
const row = page.getByRole("row").locator('[row-id="1"]:scope');

I generally avoid .filter() because the syntax is rather confusing--it uses a has: key in its object argument, breaking off of the main locator call chain.
If you're scraping rather than testing, then I'd just use plain CSS as suggested in this answer.
That said, you may want to provide more context for your use case (full HTML tree, with containers) because there could be a better way to do this. If row-ids are unique, then they're effectively data-testids, which can be queried directly, without the getByRole context query.

You can use the and locator.
await expect(page.getByRole("row").and(page.locator('[row-id="1"]'))).toHaveText("1 ROW");

But I think you can solve that with just one CSS expression.
await expect(page.locator(".table [row-id='1']")).toHaveText("1 ROW");


Your first example would also solve my problem but I have chosen the proposal from @ggorlen using :scope as I find it more readable. Thx anyhow!
